# Xcode stdint.h #error This file should only be included when compiling with MSVC

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I've got a CocoaPods React Native project in Xcode that has been working 99% of the time for the past few months. (the 1% is random stuff like this, linker errors, etc... that comes and goes seemingly at random).

I installed a new Pod and its corresponding npm dependency today, and in the past when I added pods I sometimes have issues until I try things like `pod deintegrate`, `pod install`, `react-native link` and clean the Xcode project, for example. But this time it seems nothing is fixing it.

Every time I build, whether for simulator or physical device, I get the following error from `stdint.h`

`This file should only be included when compiling with MSVC.`

It's pretty easy too find the source of the error, it's explicitly user-defined in `stdint.h`:

[image: screenshot of stdint.h]

But I can't for the life of me figure out why it's getting triggered. It says right there in the comments that MSVC is included. To my knowledge, the C-based Xcode compiler *should* provide the MSVC version to satisfy the conditional. Additionally, throughout the course of my troubleshooting/experimenting the past few hours, the culprit calling the error has changed multiple times. Right now it's coming from `RCTFBSDK` but earlier it came from `RNFirebase`.

Checking the full error tree, I can find the files requesting `stdint.h, but given that its such a fundamental file I doubt it's relevant- but here:

[image: Xcode Error tree]

**Based on my investigation so far, I'm inclined to believe it is a configuration error in Xcode causing the problem, specifically something to do with CocoaPods** (but frankly I'm not sure)

All I know is that it works without the Pod/npm dependency (which, by the way, is completely unrelated to Facebook SDK currently throwing the error) and when I add it to `package.json` and `Podfile`, do the standard `npm install` `pod install` `react-native link` this happens.

Here is what I've tried:

- Every single combination of `npm install` `npm update` `npm link` `react-native link` `pod deintegrate` `pod install`
- Deleted xcworkspace and regenerated it with `pod install`
- Removed user-defined error conditional (build was successful but crashed shortly after launch with this error: `[fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue] Exception '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array' was thrown while invoking manageChildren on target UIManager with params (...`
- Completely reinstalled Xcode
- Reverted to previous git commit (from before I added the new pod) and it worked fine
- Shook my fist at it and yelled (last resort)

Also, I have 100% confidence in my `Podfile` and `package.json` integrity. I copied the installation procedure from a well established repository.

I was very surprised to find absolutely zero information regarding this. The closest thing I found relates to C++ (understandably).

Anyone got any theories on this? Thanks. Please let me know any other specific info I did not provide.

Comment: Might be a corrupt Xcode ModuleCache. Try removing DerivedData

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I just deleted the derived data folder at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and restarted Xcode but the error still fails the build. Thanks for the suggestion, though! I hadn't even thought of trying that.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that now the issue isn't from Facebook, it's from RNFirebase.

Comment: Perhaps an incompatibility between leveldb and one of your other Pods? Are you able to share your Podfile?

Comment: I also just noticed that, unlike previous builds that were successful, `pod install` seems to have installed `nanopb` which I don't think is supposed to be there but I don't know how it got there. Here is the podfile: https://pastebin.com/TwynQfaL

Comment: nanopb is a dependency of Firebase/Analytics. The issue is related to leveldb-library which is a dependency of Firebase/Database

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I found the issue (sort of). When I installed the new pods I removed the old ones and did a fresh install- meaning all fo the pods got updated. WELLLL one of the pods that updated caused the error. I finally got past it by reverting the old Podfile.lock and Pods folder and then installing the new pod without updating the existing ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote RNFirebase co-author:

> Ye it's an annoying thing at the moment with having leveldb on cocoa pods

Here's a temporary workaround:

`cd ios && rm -rf Pods/leveldb-library/port/win`

You may also need to update your Podfile as follows:

```ruby
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
]
```

This is to avoid further errors if you're running `0.48.x`.

You may want to add the temporary workaround at the end of your `Podfile` so you don't need to worry about it:

```ruby
# Temporary workaround for https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/395
post_install do
  `rm -rf Pods/leveldb-library/port/win`
end
```

Sources:

- https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/395
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html